# How to add values of an array in php by value?

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I have this result:

```
Array ( [0] => 0, [1] => 2 ) 
Array ( [0] => 3, [1] => 3 ) 
Array ( [0] => 0, [1] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 3, [1] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 3, [1] => 3 )
```

and it comes from here:

```
 $total = array(); $i=0; $count = 0;
  foreach($dates as $d){
       $total[$i] = count($value[$d]);
       $i++;
  }
print_r ($total); echo '<br>';
```

What I want to do is add `$total[0]` like `0+3+0+3+3 = 9` and add `$total[1]` like `2+3+1+1+3 = 10`.

I only want back the 9 and the 10

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am correctly understanding the question, you have no need for additional arrays inside the loop. You simply need to accumulate each array value into a different variable:

```
$total_1 = 0;
$total_2 = 0;
foreach ($array as $a) {
  $total_1 += $a[0];
  $total_2 += $a[1];
}

echo "Total1: $total_1, Total2: $total_2";
```

If you have an unknown number of elements, use an array to sum them up by their keys.  You need an internal iterator as well.  This is, incidentally a pretty common job interview question in my experience.

```
// Array to hold all the sums
$sums = array();
foreach ($array as $a) {
  // internal iteration
  foreach ($a as $key=>$val) {
    // Add to the key if it already exists, otherwise initialize it to the current value.
    $sums[$key] = isset($sums[$key]) ? $sums[$key] += $val : $val;
  }
}

// Output your results:

foreach ($sums as $key=>$s) {
  echo "Sum of $key is $s\n";
}
```

Comment: what if i have an unknow number of values in each array? `[0] => 0 [1] => 2 [2] => 0 [3] => 2...`

Comment: @Patrioticcow See addition above - you can use an array to sum them all up with an internal iteration

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) instead of a loop.

Assuming you start with this array:

```
$dates = array(
    array(0, 2),
    array(3, 3),
    array(0, 1),
    array(3, 1),
    array(3, 3)
);
```

We define the reduce function:

```
function add_date($sum_array, $date) {
    $sum_array[0] += $date[0];
    $sum_array[1] += $date[1];
    return $sum_array;
}

$date_sums = array_reduce($dates, add_date, array(0, 0));

print_r($date_sums);
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 9
    [1] => 10
)
```

Comment: what if i have an unknow number of values in each array? `[0] => 0 [1] => 2 [2] => 0 [3] => 2...`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

```
$array = array(
    array(0, 2),
    array(3, 3),
    array(0, 1),
    array(3, 1),
    array(3, 3)
);
```

this should work for any number of arrays:

```
$results = array();
foreach ($array[0] as $i => $foo) {
    $results[] = array_sum(array_map(function ($arr) use ($i) {
                     return $arr[$i];
                 }, $array));
}
```

Note that this assumes at least one entry in `$array`, requires that all sub arrays are of equal length and needs PHP 5.3+.